# R: How to retrieve a column name of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to extract the colnames of a data frame, based on the values in the cells.  My data is a series of a couple hundred categories, with a simple binary 0 or 1 in the cells to indicate which column name I want in my new df.

To illustrate my point:

```
year cat1 cat2 cat3 ... catN
2000  0    0    1        0
2001  1    0    0        0
2002  0    0    0        1
....
2018  0    1    0        0
```

I am trying to get a df like:

```
year category 
2000  cat3
2001  cat1  
2002  catN  
....
2018  cat2
```

My code:

```
newdf <- as.data.frame(colnames(mydf)[which(mydf == "1", arr.ind = TRUE)[2]])
```

But alas this only returns one category name!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have a closer look at packages `dplyr` and `tidyr` or more complicated `data.table`. They are designed to do exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A base R solution:

Using `sapply` to find which are the ones and get the names.

```
out <- data.frame(year = df1$year, category = names(sapply(df1[, -1], function(x) which(x == 1))))

out
 year category
1 2000     cat1
2 2001     cat2
3 2002     cat3
4 2018     catN
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2018L), cat1 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), cat2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), cat3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), catN = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: ninja.  worked a charm.

Comment: so applying the above to my own data, i applied used as.data.frame to coerce my data into a data frame, but above code with this change is returning: argument "x" is missing, with no default... am i being thick about something?

Comment: I've copied the code as is, replacing df1 with my data frame name.  what could be missing in the data argument? (to clarify the data argument in sapply(df1[,-1] etc. is df1?

Comment: it outputs all the column names or "categories"

Comment: the full sapply returns the categories with their corresponding 0s or 1s.  the names(sapply...) returns something that looks like this: [1] "cat1" "cat2"           
                                                                                       [3] "cat3" "cat4"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177191/discussion-between-phiver-and-dan).

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(year = 2000:2002,
                cat1 = c(0,0,1),
                cat2 = c(1,0,0),
                cat3 = c(0,1,0))

df %>%
  gather(category, value, -year) %>%  # reshape data
  filter(value == 1) %>%              # keep rows with 1s
  select(-value) %>%                  # remove that column
  arrange(year)                       # order that column (if needed)

#   year category
# 1 2000     cat2
# 2 2001     cat3
# 3 2002     cat1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `max.col` from `base R`

```
data.frame(year = dat$year, category = names(dat[-1])[max.col(dat[-1])])
#  year category
#1 2000     cat3
#2 2001     cat1
#3 2002     catN
#4 2018     cat2
```

`max.col` finds the positions of the `1`s in your data (first column excluded) and returns a numeric vector of column positions that we use to subset the column names, again first column excluded.

Data as supplied by Rui Barradas.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
# your data
data <-data.frame(year =c(2016,2017,2018),
                  cat.1=c(0,1,0),
                  cat.2=c(0,0,1),
                  cat.3 =c(1,0,0))

# a nice library 
library(reshape2)

# from wide to long
filtered <- melt(data, id = 'year') %>% filter(value>0) 

# remove the useless column
filtered <- filtered[,1:2]
    > filtered
  year variable
1 2017    cat.1
2 2018    cat.2
3 2016    cat.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basicaly a [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) trick. To do it I will use package `reshape2`.

Then select the rows with `value == 1`.

```
result <- reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = "year")
result <- result[result$value == 1, 1:2]
result <- result[order(result[[1]]), ]
names(result)[2] <- "category"
row.names(result) <- NULL

result
#  year category
#1 2000     cat3
#2 2001     cat1
#3 2002     catN
#4 2018     cat2
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
year cat1 cat2 cat3  catN
2000  0    0    1   0
2001  1    0    0   0
2002  0    0    0   1
2018  0    1    0   0
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another base R option using `stack`

```
subset(data.frame(year = df$year, stack(df, select = -year)), values == 1)[-2]
#   year  ind
#2  2001 cat1
#8  2018 cat2
#9  2000 cat3
#15 2002 catN
```